# Email Settings tab shown on another user's profile

Tags: bug, profile-page

When viewing your own Stack Overflow profile using Chrome on an Android phone -
 that is, when using the mobile version of Stack Overflow - an "Email Settings" tab is displayed alongside the usual "Profile" and "Activity" tabs.

Whether or not that's intended, I have no idea.

However, it's also displayed when viewing the profile of another user. And clicking it results in a "Page Not Found" error.

Comment: Was able to duplicate on iOS on Google Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Confirmed on firefox for android. Probably not browser-dependent at all. Definitely not [meta-tag:by-design], and almost certainly related to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298906/control-the-types-of-email-you-receive-via-our-new-email-settings-feature